# jq not working on tag name with dashes and numbers

Tags: json, bash, jq

I am using `jq` but having "-" in my json tag make `jq` not compile. I cannot escape it to make it works. Here is the command:

```bash
curl -X GET -H "X-AppKey:foo" "foo/v2/_status" | jq '.component-status[]'
```

I have read in the github of `jq` this post https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/202 but I cannot make it work.

This is the output of the `curl`:

```
{
  "status": "ok",
  "hostname": "0b0b495a46db",
  "component-status": [
   {
     "status-code": 200,
     "component": "Service1",
     "status": "OK"
   },
   {
     "status-code": 200,
     "component": "Service2",
     "status": "OK"
   }
  ]
 }
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 158, accepted):

You need to enclose in brackets and double quotes:

```
jq '."component-status"'
```

With your given input it returns:

```
[
  {
    "status": "OK",
    "component": "Service1",
    "status-code": 200
  },
  {
    "status": "OK",
    "component": "Service2",
    "status-code": 200
  }
]
```

The [jq Manual (development) --> Basic filters](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Basicfilters):

> ```
> .foo, .foo.bar
> ```
>
> The simplest useful filter is `.foo`. When given a JSON object (aka
>   dictionary or hash) as input, it produces the value at the key “foo”,
>   or null if there’s none present.
>
> If the key contains special characters, you need to surround it with
>   double quotes like this: `."foo$"`.

From the github issue [Cannot select field if field name has dashes](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/38#issuecomment-9770240):

> Currently, that gets parsed as a subtraction. You can always
>   explicitly use strings for when your keys don't fit identifier syntax.

Comment: Using the form .["quoted-name"] has the advantage of working in all versions of jq.  In jq version 1.4 and up, the shorter form ."quoted-name" is also supported

Comment: @peak thanks for the insight! Do you have links for that, so I can add to the answer? My `jq`-fu is limited and all I did here was try a bit and find the explanation in a github issue from the `jq` project.

Comment: The "development version" of the manual (https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/) has links to other versions.

The jq FAQ (https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/FAQ) also discusses the issue.

From the "development version":

> If the key contains special characters, you need to surround it with double quotes like this: ."foo$".

Comment: I've run into cases where the square brackets (`.["hyphenated-string"]`) actually causes an error: `jq: error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting FORMAT or QQSTRING_START (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>`. Whereas just adding double quotes (`."hyphenated-string"`) worked fine.

Comment: @BrianV You can repro with this: `echo '{"a-a":{"b-b": "huzzah"}}'| jq '.["a-a"]."b-b"'`. As typed, it works. But if you put a `[ ]` around `"b-b"` you get that error. `'."a-a"."b-b"'` also works.

Comment: @BrianV I have this issue too, so I've edited the answer to use '."key-name"' instead of brackets, which bash can't handle.

Comment: @Trenton fixed :)

Comment: @Trenton - The square-bracket form `.["KEYNAME"]` works in all versions of jq (unlike the ."KEYNAME" form), but to abbreviate `.["a-a"]|.["b-b"]` you would have to write `.["a-a"]["b-b"]` -- that is, drop the "|" and the ".".

Comment: `jq '."component-status"'` just yields the string "component-status". The variant with the square brackets actually works.

Answer (score 7):

The [option suggested by rjurney](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37344329/jq-not-working-on-tag-name-with-dashes-and-numbers/37344498#37344498) or the commenters to his answers did not work for me (probably because I used PowerShell), however in [the answer from github issue](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/38#issuecomment-65294088) there was a solution, which did the trick - escaping double quotation marks with \

```
jq '.\"component-status\"'
```

Comment: @DivDev - Please be explicit about the computing environment you have in mind.  This solution will not work in bash and bash-like shells.

Comment: @peak, it was PowerShell, I added it to the answer

Comment: It works on redhat 8 also