# Json filter not working on array while using jq

Tags: json, filtering, jq

i have the following json format and trying to filter it using jq.
My requirement is to print the "read-transactions" value.
I. tried the following but didnt succeed.

```
validator-info --json | jq .Node_info.Metrics[].read-transactions
```

Expected output is 0.1233

Any idea what I'm missing here?

```
{
Node_info": {
    "Metrics": {
      "Delta": 0.12,
      "Lambda": 2410,
      "Omega": 220,
      "average-per-second": {
        "read-transactions": 0.1233,
        "write-transactions": 0.122334
      },
      }
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should work. This is as per this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/37344498/1109657

```
validator-info --json | jq '.Node_info.Metrics."average-per-second"."read-transactions"'
```

Answer (score 0):

> Json filter not working ***on array*** while using jq

There are **no** arrays in your JSON, only objects

---

Since there are some `-`'s in your path, you'll need to pass the key as string like so:

```
jq '.Node_info.Metrics."average-per-second"."read-transactions"'
```

This will output (after making the JSON valid):

```
0.1233
```

---

##### [JqPlay Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/Am64PnTUJK)